# How to print out a file's name with extension without the directory

Tags: python, sqlite, operating-system, python-os

I'm trying to format the following file: C:\Users\Johnny\Downloads\Misc\ticket.jpg
to just print out only the file name and extension but I keep getting stuck. Is there a simple way to do this in Python3?

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import os

conn = sqlite3.connect(sys.argv[1], uri=True)
curr = conn.cursor()
dwld = curr.execute("select * FROM downloads")

file_name = curr.execute("select current_path from downloads ORDER BY end_time DESC")
file_result = file_name.fetchone(`
file_no_dir = file_result[0]
path = file_no_dir
```

```
# Input
print(os.path.basename(path).split('/')[-1])
```

Expected Output:

```
ticket.jpg
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Johnny\Downloads\Misc\ticket.jpg
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample output of `file_name` variable right after:
`file_name = curr.execute("select current_path from downloads ORDER BY end_time DESC")`?

Comment: The output is was a tuple from a database so [ ('C:\\Users\\Johnny\\Documents\\Misc\\ticket.jpg',), ('C:\\Users\\Steve\\Pictures\\ MS Setup.png',)]

Answer (score 0):

You should [escape the backslashes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp) before. Like so:

```
path_with_backslashes = "test\123.jpg"
corrected_path = path_with_backslashes.replace('\\', '\\\\')
```

The issue with the line print(os.path.basename(path).split('/')[-1]) is that you are using forward slashes (/) in the split() method while the path you provided uses backslashes ().
On Windows, the path separator is a backslash, so you should split by backslashes. You can use os.path.sep to get the appropriate separator for your platform.
Here's the corrected line:

```py
print(os.path.basename(corrected_path ).split(os.path.sep)[-1])
```

A (better) way would be to use `os.path.basename()`, because that doesn't require the `split()` method. You can simply use:

```py
print(os.path.basename(corrected_path))
```

This should give you the expected output.

Adding this to your code sample:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import os

conn = sqlite3.connect(sys.argv[1], uri=True)
curr = conn.cursor()
dwld = curr.execute("select * FROM downloads")

file_name = curr.execute("select current_path from downloads ORDER BY end_time DESC")
file_result = file_name.fetchone(`
file_no_dir = file_result[0]
path = file_no_dir.replace('\\', '\\\\')
print(os.path.basename(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
filename = os.path.basename(path)
```